# Primefaces: Enable multiple selection in datatable filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

I'm using Prime-faces 4. I have requirement like, in Data-table filter user wants to select more than one option. But, i think in Prime-faces, user can select only one option. Can any one help me how can i achieve this?

Cheers,
Tej.

Answer (score 2):

Try using global filter in datatable header

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
    onkeyup="widgetVarTable.filter()" />
    <p:watermark value="Search here" for="globalFilter"/>
</f:facet>
```

See this link for more help http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml